# Connect Excel WorkSheet in OleContainer

Tags: excel, delphi, containers, ole, worksheet

I need connect an Excel WorkSheet in OleContainer.
I can do, saving the WorkSheet in disk:

```
// Get the WorkSheet and save to disk
Globals.Xls.getHoja().SaveAs('D:\test.xls',...,emptyParam,emptyParam,emptyParam);
// Load the WorkSheet from the disk
OleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile('D:\test.xls',false);
```

But, exist any way, to connect without save the WorkSheet ?. Ergo, load inside the OleContainer the instance of _WorkSheet returned by `Globals.Xls.getHoja()`.

Im newest in Delphi and Windows programming, and i dont know every things je.

Thanks !.

Comment: you can show it, but then that would be an object within your program, not a separate Excel process. That might be a very different behaviour than you and your customers expect

Comment: open BabelFish or Google Translate or anything and scan through http://www.sql.ru/forum/1026756/eshhyo-vopros-pro-ole-konteyner?hl=olecontainer http://www.sql.ru/forum/681265/olecontainer-excel-application-kak-sovmestit?hl=olecontainer and some unexpected consequences like disabled menus : http://www.sql.ru/forum/881614/tolecontainer-excel-nedostupno-menu-fayl-i-pr?hl=olecontainer etc http://www.sql.ru/forum/afsearch.aspx?s=olecontainer&submit=%CD%E0%E9%F2%E8&bid=20